# Observable<Observable<Event>[]> to Observable<Event>[]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to create a function which merges all `fromEvent`'s created from an array of `datachannels` and emits any event that will be received from any of them.

This is the initial function:

```
  private dataChannels: BehaviorSubject<RTCDataChannel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  // datachannels array get filled at some point
  ...

  public on(): Observable<Event> {
    const eventStreams = this.dataChannels.value.map((c) => fromEvent(c, 'message'));
    return merge(...eventStreams);
  }
```

However the problem with the function above is, as I understand it, that new values emitted to the datachannels behaviorsubject will **not** be used.

Thus I started creating the following function:

```
  const allEvents = this.dataChannels.pipe(map((channels) => channels.map((c) => fromEvent(c, 'message'))));

  return merge(...allEvents);
```

Here is where my problem arises. `allEvents` is of type `Observable<Observable<Event>[]>`. Which the `merge` will not accept. How do I resolve the observable to type `Observable<Event>[]`?

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to the `dataChannels`?

Comment: @VRoxa Because the function is in an angular service, which will be called/subscribed to somewhere else.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to emit every `RTCDataChannel` "received" mapped to with the function `fromEvent` which takes the `RTCDataChannel` as the first parameter, plus `'message'`, isn't it?

Comment: @VRoxa Yes. Then the multiple `fromEvent`'s will start receiving events, which will be returned through the subscription (whoever is subscribed to the `on` function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merging all the Observables you receive in BehaviorSubject.
 The issue which I see is pending subscriptions of channels even if they are removed from the dataChannels.
 I have createad a classn prop `newSubscription$`, all `fromEvent` would unsubscribe when this is emitted.

You can try out this solution.

```
    newSubscription$ = new Subject();
    this.dataChannels.pipe(
        tap(() => {
            this.newSubscription$.next();   // kill existing subscriptions
            this.newSubscription$ = new Subject(); // and wait for this for new ones
        }) 
        switchMap((allChannels) => {
        const fromEvenObs = allChannels.map(c => fromEvent(c, 'message').pipe(takeUntil(newSubscription$)));
        return merge(...fromEvenObs);
    })).subscribe((data) => { // data from any event});
```

**EDIT:**

Since we are using `switchMap()`, there won't be a requirement of having an extra observable to unsubscribe `events` when `dataChannels` receive new Data. Just doing the following would be sufficient:

```
this.dataChannels.pipe(
    switchMap((allChannels) => {
        const fromEvenObs = allChannels.map(c => fromEvent(c, 'message'));
        return merge(...fromEvenObs);
})).subscribe((data) => { //data from events });
```

Comment: This works great. I only had to add `map((m) => JSON.parse(m.data)` in the `fromEvent`'s pipe to receive proper data.

Comment: @lars please check out if we actually need the extra unsubscription subject, or all inner observables be automatically unsubscribed when we use a `switchMap`. (It should actually unsubscribe)

Comment: When I call `this.dataChannels.next([]);` the receival of new events/messages seem to stop (without the unsubscription subject).

Comment: @lars cool then, with `switchMap` you do not need the unsubscription subject then

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `mergeAll`, as the documentation says `mergeAll subscribes to an Observable that emits Observables. Each time it observes one of these emitted inner Observables, it subscribes to that and delivers all the values from the inner Observable on the output Observable.`

And use the operator `from` to emit each observable of the array of observable.

```js
const allEvents = this.dataChannels.pipe(
   map((channels) => from(channels.map((c) => fromEvent(c, 'message'))),
   mergeAll();
);
```